# How i get form value using multiactioncontroller instead fo simpleformcontroller in spring

Tags: spring-mvc

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'forum' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:175)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:195)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:161)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:148)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:139)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:123)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:140)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:78)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.ForumList_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(ForumList_jsp.java:189)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.ForumList_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(ForumList_jsp.java:138)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.ForumList_jsp._jspService(ForumList_jsp.java:94)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:239)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:709)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:613)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:525)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

**i can't unable to bind commandName in multiactioncontroller becoz there are not setCommandName and setCommandClass method(methodSimpleFormController)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to do simply `request.getParameter("parameterName");` if you extend `MultiActionController`. To utilize `setCommand()` extend `SimpleFormController`

Update (for more understanding upon getParameter() method ) :

Suppose you have a form like this :

```
<form action="myController.html" method="post">
    Name : <input type="text" name="username" value="${param.username}" />
    <%--
       That ${param.username} will help pre-populating the value 
       of the text field with `username` parameter
    --%> 
</form>
```

And in your controller method, retrieve the submitted parameter like :

```
public ModelAndView myControllerMethod(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
}
```

As said, you cannot use bean with extending `MultiActionController`, you need to do it for all the bean attributes individually.

Comment: Actually i have found that multiactioncontroller is not command controller so this is not possible a/c http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html . is it right or not?????

Comment: yes you are right. `multiactioncontroller` is not command controller.

Comment: nops, not possible with `bind()` too. `request.getParameter()` is the only way for `MultiActionController`

Comment: <form:form action="user/addForum.htm" commandName="forum"> means i don't right that code for multiActionController means i am unable to set commandName attribute ,becoz if use it then i got above problem and if i am not put that attribute then also i get error pls give some example like if i using request.getparameter("") method

Comment: it means we can't use spring form tag with multiActionController